# How to make a linux executable file using gitlab (go env)?

Tags: go, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to make a Linux executable file of my Go project. I have the following configuration in my `.config-ci.yml` in my gitlab project.

```yaml
demo_job_1:
    tags:
        - cpf
        - cpf-test
        - testing
        - unit-testing
    script:
        - go run test/main.go
        - GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
        - go env
        - cd test
        - ./test
        - echo Successfully run and Built
```

After running this pipeline, I still get the GOOS=windows when I check in env file. How can I build my project so that the output after building is of Linux executable file. Right now, I am getting .exe file which runs on Windows only.

You can see the project details in the following gitlab:

https://gitlab.com/smilekison/test

This is the error that is shown by Pipeline Job:

```
$ go run test/main.go
Hello world
$ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build

GOOS=linux : The term 'GOOS=linux' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\build_script487326907\script.ps1:207 char:1
+ GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (GOOS=linux:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Can you try removing "go env"? just use GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build

Comment: @GokhanMANKARA.. Thank you for suggestion... I am currently running pipeline regarding your suggesion.

Comment: @GokhanMANKARA. I have update the question according to your suggestion and the pipeline failed. I have uploaded the error as well. Can you help me out. Thank You.

Comment: What kind of gitlab runner do you have? Best use one with docker. If you already have that, add the `image` keyword to specify which image you want to use. See my answer below.

Comment: @TehSphinX.. Thank you for you reply. I am completely beginner at gitlab. I am trying to learn GitLab. I have not used artifacts yet. So, I am just trying to build so that the executable file will run on Linux. That's all. I don't know if there is GO BUILD and some parameters that create Linux executable file directly. Hope, You understand. Thank You

Comment: Then I guess this is for you. https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html Note that windows and docker do not mix well. If you have access to a unix machine (e.g. a server) it will be a lot easier to install a runner there for docker. Our docker runner is itself a docker container running on a linux VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to address your actual error: it seems you are on a windows based runner. That means you have to use windows CMD commands. It does not know ENV, etc.

You can do `go env -w GOOS="linux"` instead. Same with GOARCH. Then just run `go build .`.

You can also use a variables section to overwrite `go env` with environment variables:

```
variables:
  GOOS: "linux"
  GOARCH: "amd64"
```

It goes at the top of the gitlab file somewhere.

---

Here my typical build pipeline for Go projects using docker containers:

```
build_App:
  image: golang:1.15.3
  stage: build
  allow_failure: false
  tags:
    - unix
  script:
    - go mod download
    - mkdir $CI_PROJECT_DIR/release
    - cd cmd/app
    - GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o $CI_PROJECT_DIR/release/app .
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/release
```

And test pipeline

```
go_test:
  image: golang:1.15.3
  stage: verify
  allow_failure: false
  tags:
    - unix
  script:
    - go mod download
    - go test -race -cover ./...
```

---

This is based on a runner that uses docker images to build in.

Comment: I adjusted my answer to address your actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to write ***go env -w GOOS="linux" GOARCH="amd64"*** to make the executable file for linux and if I want to make executable for windows I have to just rename **linux** to **windows** and I can make go language install by using   ***image : golang:1.15.7*** here. This way my .gitlab-ci.yml file can get GO Lang install and can run any go command.

```
demo_job_1:
stages:
  -build
    
build:
  stage: build
  image : golang:1.15.7
  tags:
    - cpf
    - cpf-test
    - testing
    - unit-testing
  script:
    - go run test/main.go
    - go env -w GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64
    - go env
    - cd test
    - ./test
    - echo Successfully run and Built
```